# Getting the test that is executing in `setUp`

Tags: phpunit

Is there a way to get the test that is about to be executed (the actual **Function name**) inside `setUp()` in ***PHPUnit***?

I know that I can put the code inside the test function itself instead of `setUp()`, but I have created some **Abstract** Test Cases and since `setUp()` takes a long time to execute, I want to be able skip unnecessary actions or even tests inside `setUp()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getName` method that return the name of the test case (the function that is been called). If you pass true as arguments it will return the name of the dataset (in case of dataprovider). So simply use:

```
public function setUp()
{
    var_dump($this->getName(false) );  // The name of the method without dataprovider

    var_dump(get_called_class()); // The name of the TestCase Class
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Brief and on Point. Perfect.