# PHPUnit - Getting the executing method in tearDown method

Tags: php, phpunit, tdd

I have two methods in one test e.g.:

1. `TestOne()`
2. `TestTwo()`

And I have `tearDown` method also in my test.

```
public function tearDown()
{
    // here i want to get the current callable method because tearDown method is called after every method
    $status = $this->getStatus();
    \Log::info("\n\nEnd of exception ".$status);
        if ($status == PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_ERROR 
                || $status == PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_FAILURE) {
                    \Log::info("\n Failed Exception");
            // take a screenshot...
        }
}
```

Comment: `$this->getName()`?

Comment: check if this can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/39534399/2270041

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the test that is executing in \`setUp\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533865/getting-the-test-that-is-executing-in-setup)